# Obtaining number of images after using imagedatagenerator() in keras and before training

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

Below is the sample code, that I am trying to use. I want to know if there is any way to get the number of images immediately after applying imagedatagenerator() and before performing training (i.e, .fit_generator). The reason is, I want to use these images later for training instead of my original dataset.

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                 #featurewise_center=True,
                                 samplewise_center=True,
                                 zca_epsilon=1e-06,
                                 #channel_shift_range=100.0,
                                 #samplewise_std_normalization=True,
                                 #featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                                 rotation_range=15,
                                 #width_shift_range=0,
                                 #height_shift_range=0,
                                 shear_range=0.2,
                                 fill_mode='nearest',
                                 zoom_range=0.1,
                                 horizontal_flip= True,
                                )

val_datagen= ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                 samplewise_center=True,
                               )

train_generator= train_datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)
val_generator= val_datagen.flow(X_val, Y_val,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)

history= model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                            batch_size= batch_size,
                            steps_per_epoch=trainSize,
                            epochs=10,
                            validation_data=val_generator,
                            validation_steps=valSize,
                            callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)]
                            #callbacks=[es_callback]
                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because `ImageDataGenerator` can generate augmented images indefinitely, and the final number of generated images used for training is a function of the `batch_size`, `steps_per_epoch` and number of epochs you train for. You can use the `save_to_dir` argument of the `flow()` method of your generator to save the augmented images. The number of images should equal `batch_size` times `steps_per_epoch` times `epochs`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, don't we have to set a definite range when we use `save_to_dir` argument of `flow()`. Or could we get augmented images irrespective of any range?